# Copy list from a dynamic object

Tags: c#, list

I am writing a conversion method. I'm creating an object of type A and receiving an object of type B. Both type A and B are the same in content with the same parameters but different namespaces.

```
    static CompositeType temp = new CompositeType();        
    static ServiceReference.CompositeType B = new ServiceReference.CompositeType();   
    public static void clone(dynamic composite) //B passed here
    {
        temp.mName = composite.mName;
        temp.mCpuUsage = composite.mCpuUsage;
        temp.mRamAvailable = composite.mRamAvailable;
        temp.mTimeAlive = composite.mTimeAlive;
        //So far so good, everything is OK.

        temp.deks = composite.deks.ToList(); //This throws an exception
        temp.deks = new List<type>(composite.deks); //this doesn't work either
    }
```

The exception:

> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List.Add(serv.type)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: What type is `composite.deks`?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov :-) :-) :-) Same text, same formatting :-)

Comment: If they really have the same types, then `temp.deks = composite.deks` is enough

Comment: `composite.deks` is of type `<type>`, it's initialized like this `List<type> deks = new List<type>();`

Comment: And why are you using `dynamic` here, if you know the type involved? It sounds like the actual problem would be solved by writing a conversion method from one of your list element types to the other, then using `temp.deks = composite.deks.Select(ConvertDek).ToList()` or whatever...

Comment: @xanatos LOL, i know. Deleted mine :P

Comment: @xanatos same exception. The method uses dynamic because there are going to be many objects passed with different namespaces but same content.

Comment: can you provide declaration for `CompositeType` and `ServiceReference.CompositeType`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Skeet, but note that you can't directly use LINQ methods, because extensions methods aren't automatically usable with dynamic:

```
IEnumerable<dynamic> deks = composite.deks;
temp.deks = deks.Select(ConvertSubItem).ToList();
```

And then:

```
static deksamenes ConvertSubItem(dynamic subItem)
{
    var sub = new deksamenes();
    sub.Something = subItem.Something;
    return sub;
}
```

Note that this won't work if the item type of `deks` is a value type (an `int` for example).

(`IEnumerable<dynamic>` should work because `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant, so that `IEnumerable<Foo>` can be implicitly casted to `IEnumerable<object>` or `IEnumerable<dynamic>` if `Foo` is a reference type)

Comment: There is no `CompositeTypeSubType` do you mean `CompositeType`? Also the `.Something` needs to change?

Comment: @George You just added the exact names. I had to invent some names.

Comment: My exception: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ekoserv.CompositeType>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ekoserv.deksamenes>' `

Comment: @George Have you modified the `ConvertSubItem`?

Comment: `static CompositeType ConvertSubItem(dynamic serviceReferenceSubType)
        {
            var sub = new CompositeType();
            sub.deks = serviceReferenceSubType.deks;
            return sub;
        }`

Comment: @George I had modified my response 11 minutes ago, when you first commented. And instead of Something you'll have to add your properties

Comment: Ok i just saw you updated you post!!!!! Well it works and i'm getting frustrated cause i don't know how to upgrate my skill to a better level.....

Comment: @George It is something that comes one step at a time... Unless it doesn't come, then you can be worried :-)

Comment: Things just like this you wrote are not written in books. (At least at those i read). I'm a self-learned programmer and just happens to enjoy it btw. I guess it takes experience and time. How many years do you works(?) as a programmer?

Comment: I'm 4 months in. There is time i guess! :D Thank you for your assist.